# run tasks of ansible role on multiple hosts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-galaxy

I wrote an ansible role to install elasticsearch multi node cluster,
the problème is that i have a configuration files for each type of node (Master, Data).I have a problem to specify the host in each playbook.

setup_elastic.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  roles:
  - elasticsearch
```

and here is the config file for masters:

```
---
    - name: config elasticsearch master
      blockinfile:
          path: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
          block: |
                    cluster.name: lamedicale4
                    node.master: true
                    node.data: false
                    node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
                    bootstrap.mlockall: true
                    path.data: /data/elasticsearch
                    path.logs: /logs/elasticsearch
                    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
                    discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
                    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts : ["172.31.36.229","172.31.44.124"]
```

config file for data nodes:

```
---
    - name: config elasticsearch data nodes
      blockinfile:
          path: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
          block: |
                    cluster.name: lamedicale4
                    node.master: false
                    node.data: true
                    node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
                    bootstrap.mlockall: true
                    path.data: /data/elasticsearch
                    path.logs: /logs/elasticsearch
                    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
                    discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
                    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts : ["172.31.36.229","172.31.44.124"]
```

and here is the main tasks:

```
---
# tasks file for /etc/ansible/roles/elastissearch

- import_tasks: install_java_jdk.yml
- import_tasks: install_elasticsearch.yml
- import_tasks: clear_file.yml
- import_tasks: directory_data_log_elastic.yml
- include_tasks: config_elasticsearch_master.yml
- include_tasks: config_elasticsearch_data.yml
- import_tasks: reload_restart_elasticsearch.yml
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your specific question, replace `${HOSTNAME}` with either:

- {{ inventory_hostname }}
- {{ ansible_fqdn }}
- {{ ansible_hostname }}

Have a look at [this part of the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts) to understand where these come from.

More generally, I would suggest that a more flexible approach to 'blockinfile', would be to convert the whole config file to an Ansible template, and manage it with the ['template' module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html). I have done this in the past with Elasticsearch config files and it has worked well.